# Do git-cheetah windows explorer integrations conflict with tortoise svn?

Tags: git, svn, windows-explorer

I already have tortoise svn installed to access a remote repository for a client project and it has the specialized icons in windows explorer.  Installing git on my machine for my own development purposes and it is asking to install git-cheetah for windows explorer integrations.

I know that I could do command line for either/both, but I like the use of svn through explorer and would like to use git the same way.  Has anyone encountered problems having both installed in that manner?  Or does last app installed win?

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and installed this morning.  So far, so good, so I would say no conflicts.  Frankly, seeing the implementation now, this seems like a silly question.  Probably a hangover response on my part from all of the browsers/toolbars competing to be default...

Answer (score 1):

They should interoperate nicely, with one caveat:  there is [a limited number of "icon overlays"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2012/01/09/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-icon-overlays-in-shell-extensions-tfs-power-tools.aspx) available to shell extensions.

If you have several Windows Explorer extensions that each decorate file status using icons then you will eventually exhaust the icon overlay space.  When that happens, you will stop seeing the icon overlays.